# jQuery Plugin Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

does anyone know why theme animations can affect the waypoints plugin (http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) from working properly and maybe how to solve this?

I am using the plugin within my wordpress theme to toggle a class of my header when it has scrolled down a certain amount of another element to make some smooth shrinking effect. It works really easy and great.

However, as soon as I add some animations, given by the theme to the page, the plugin stops working correctly. Instead the class is added arbitrary or even not at all.

I don't get any error messages in the debugger.

I am using following code snippet to toggle my header with the waypoint plugin:

```
var waypoints = jQuery('#hd-anm-anchor').waypoint({
handler: function(direction) {
jQuery('.fusion-header').toggleClass('header-active', direction === 'down');
},
offset: '-15%'
});
```

Comment: By adding jQuery( window ).load( function() { }); I was able to get the plugin to fire everytime. But sometimes there still appear some conflicts (sometimes the animated text does not appear or if I reload in the middle of the page, css transitions are not correctly anymore)

I also checked the theme main.js and recognized that it is using an older version of the same plugin. But I have no clue how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so I'm going to try to answer your question. A solution to the problem could perhaps be if you use the older version of the plugin to toggle your header rather than the newer version. If you're using two versions of the same plugin both installed on the same instance of wordpress you're going to run into a ton of problems where there's conflicting commands

Comment: Hi, yeah, I thought so. The problem is, that the plugin api's documentation is just for the newest version. I already tried to delete the newest version and let the jQuery call inside my custom.js. In this case the class is not toggled, so it seems that the api has changed between the old and new version :(